# I'm using OpenLayers with GeoWebCache. I need to change the Default Storage location to Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: dictionary, amazon-s3, geolocation, openlayers, gis

I'm learning to use *OpenLayers* and *GeoWebCache*.

My ultimate task is to use the *Amazon S3* bucket as a storage cache location for *GeoWebCache*.

I can change this storage location to any local disk location (http://geowebcache.org/docs/1.5.1/configuration/layers/howto.html).

But don't know how to move to S3 bucket. Cos in `geowebcache-core-context.xml` I don't see a place to give credential for Amazon account.

Please suggest any solutions anyone have.

Answer (score 0):

GeoWebCache uses geoserver to generate tiles to the filesystem and uses this filesystem structure of images, so I'm not sure if you can pull them from the amazon service.

If you found a way to retrieve the images with the help of a link (not filesystem request), you could use something like ashx handler (provided you use .net) to forward your request and add credentials to that request.